# How to wait for Akka actor system to terminate?

Tags: scala, akka

I need to start Akka (2.0) actor system, send in some messages, then wait for it to do heavy lifting. After that, I need to do something unrelated to those actors.

I tried to wait for all actors to stop with following code:

```
val system = new ActorSystem("parallelRunners")
val master = system.actorOf(Props[Master])
master ! Start
system.awaitTermination // <-- hangs here
```

All actors kill themselves via `self ! PoisonPill`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Akka 2.4.1 for scala 2.11 it appears to be different again.

`system.awaitTermination()` is deprecated and the docs instruct us to use `Await.result(system.whenTerminated, timeout)` instead.

As [203](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2148890/203) said, `system.terminate` is still the way to terminate the system.

Here is some example code I used:

```
val actorSystem = ActorSystem("ActorSystem")
val myActors = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(10)), "MyActors")
rainbows.foreach(rainbow => myActors ! rainbow)
Await.ready(actorSystem.whenTerminated, Duration(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
```

Then in the MyActor class I have the line `context.system.terminate()`

Answer (score 7):

As of Akka 2.4, you should use `system.awaitTermination()` which returns a `Future[Terminated]` you can wait for.

In order to terminate the system, you should use `ActorSystem.terminate` (e.g. `context.system.terminate()` from within an actor when it is finished.

Source: [Release Notes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/project/migration-guide-2.3.x-2.4.x.html#Actor_system_shutdown)

Answer (score 6):

Just a side note for those running into this question for its title: Apparently, Akka 2.5 does not support `actorSystem.awaitTermination` anymore. Reason being why might be Akka's philosophy of avoiding any blocking calls. Instead, `actorSystem.registerOnTermination(...)` can be used as a non-blocking way to do actions while an `ActorSystem` is being shutdown.

Nonetheless, you can still wait for your actor system to complete via a `Future` provided by `ActorSystem.whenTerminated`:

```
val system = new ActorSystem("parallelRunners")
val master = system.actorOf(Props[Master])
master ! Start

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
Await.ready(system.whenTerminated, 365.days)
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution - just call system.shutdown from the master actor:

```
context.system.shutdown
```

Comment: Please note: [as of Akka 2.4](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/project/migration-guide-2.3.x-2.4.x.html#Actor_system_shutdown), you should use `ActorSystem.terminate()` instead of `ActorSystem.shutdown()`

Answer (score 4):

You can also kill the `ActorSystem` from the main thread by using `system.shutdown`. But that operation is asynchronous. You only need to use `system.awaitTermination` if you need to block the main thread until it completes. If your parallelRunners return something useful for the rest of the program, then it would probably be easiest to not block and continue your program.

Answer (score 0):

in Akka 2.3.9, it seems that shutting down an actor system and waiting for it to shut down is a two step process:

1. Initiate the shutdown: 
   `actorSystem.shutdown`
2. Wait for its termination in a blocking manner: 
   `actorSystem.awaitTermination`

As an alternative to step (2), possibly (haven't tested these alternatives) you may alternatively poll on `isTerminated` or use `registerOnTermination` for running some code when it's terminated. So it is worth going through the comments of akka.actor.ActorSystem to fathom and choose between these methods for your implementation.

Perhaps I'm missing other options about the API (?) as `Future` return values could have been nicer.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

Await.ready(system.terminate(), 5.seconds)
```

terminate returns a Future:

```
def terminate(): Future[Terminated]
```

and you can just await completion of this future.